# CSS Dropdown menu and footer

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to figure this out for a long while, but I still can't seem to fix it.

I created the dropdown menu but when it drops down, it is covered by the MAIN section and thus, won't show.  Also, my footer is not being displayed at the bottom of the page.

I used `clear:both` for every section of my page, but the footer is being displayed under the `aside` section instead of the `main` section.

[image: Situation explained]

#### HTML Code

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>News</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
            <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script>
                document.createElement(“article”);
                document.createElement(“aside”);
                document.createElement(“footer”);
                document.createElement(“header”);
                document.createElement(“main”);
                document.createElement(“nav”);
                document.createElement(“section”);
            </script>
            <![endif]-->
        </head>
        <body>
            <header class="banner">
                <h1>News</h1>
                <p>Local and National News</p>
            </header>

            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="archive.html">Archives</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="January.html">January</a></li>
                            <li><a href="February.html">February</a></li>
                            <li><a href="March.html">March</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

            <main class = "content">
                <section>
                    <h2>Local News</h2>
                    <article>
                        <header>
                            <h3>Fire fighters rescue man from building</h3>
                            <p>(author, date)</p><br>
                        </header>
                        <p>This is the story text. This is the story text.</p>
                        <p>This is the story text. This is the story text.</p>
                    </article>

                    <article>
                        <header>
                            <h3>New Library to be built</h3>
                            <p>(author, date)</p> <br>
                        </header>
                        <p>This is the story text. This is the story text.</p>
                        <p>This is the story text. This is the story text.</p>
                    </article>
                </section>

                <section>
                    <h2>National News</h2>
                    <article>
                        <header>
                        <h3>Snow storm is making travel difficult</h3>
                        <p>(author, date)</p><br>
                        </header>
                        <p>This is the story text. This is the story text.</p>
                        <p>This is the story text. This is the story text.</p>
                    </article>

                    <article>
                        <header>
                            <h3>Thousands are without power</h3>
                            <p>(author, date)</p><br>
                        </header>
                        <p>This is the story text. This is the story text.</p>
                        <p>This is the story text. This is the story text.</p>      
                    </article>
                </section>

            </main>


            <aside class = "content">
                <section class="reporter">
                    <h2>Be a news reporter!</h2>
                    <p>If you see news happening - <br>Send us a Text!</p>
                </section>
                <section class="bell">
                    <h2>Bell Canada</h2>
                    <article>
                        <header>
                            <h3>We have new phones coming out!
                        </header>
                        <p> Samsung Galaxy S5!</p>
                        <p> iPhone 6! </p>
                    </article>
                </section>
            </aside>

            <footer class = "content">
                <p>Footer Information</p>
            </footer>

        </body>
    </html>
```

#### CSS Code

```
@charset "UTF-8"

article, aside, footer, header, main, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

html, body, h1, h2, h3, ul, li, a, p,
article, aside, footer, header, main, nav, section {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.banner {
    background-color: #11233b;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;  
}

nav{
    background-color: #20416c;
    color: white;
    padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}

nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

nav li ul li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    display: block;
}

nav li{
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #20416c;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #20416c;
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    visibility: visible;
    display: block;
}

nav li:hover {
    background-color:maroon;
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li a{
    color: white;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}

section {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}

article {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

main {
    position: absolute;
    width: 640px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

aside {
    clear: both;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    width: 270px;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

aside section.reporter p {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

aside section.bell p {
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

aside section {
    background-color: #888888;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.content{
    clear: both;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    background-color: #20416c;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px;
}
```

Comment: please post some screenshots and mark on it what you mean please (or jsfiddle, or something to demonstrate this kind of problem)

Comment: i added an image!  its under the code. thanks!

Comment: @user3642781 Remember to select correct answer afterwards and upvote any answers that you'll find useful. [And welcome to community](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Changing the z-index can work, however, it really doesn't address the root of the issue.

The "main" element is position absolutely unnecessarily; or so it appears to me. If you make the following changes to the CSS, you won't need to change the z-index.

```
main {
    /* REMOVED: position: absolute;*/
    width: 640px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

aside {
    /* REMOVED: clear: both;
    position: relative;*/
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    width: 270px;
    float: right;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}

.content{
    /* REMOVED: clear: both;*/
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JjwMw/4/

Also fixes the footer issue.